# How to add "load more" button on blogger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, infinite-scroll

I want to add a "load more" button on a blogger page.I have found [this exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/bEdfX/) .But I don't know where to put each part of code on blogger (HTML / CSS / JavaScript) ,especially this jQuery part of code.

```
$(function(){
    $("div").slice(0, 10).show(); // select the first ten
    $("#load").click(function(e){ // click event for load more
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div:hidden").slice(0, 10).show(); // select next 10 hidden divs and show them
        if($("div:hidden").length == 0){ // check if any hidden divs still exist
            alert("No more divs"); // alert if there are none left
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The provided example loads all the content at once and displays it ten items at a time. I doubt this is your desired effect, and I think you may want to load the post real-time using Ajax.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Actually, That's what I want to do, I don't want to display all the content at once to avoid having a long page, I want to create a button that displays more content each time you hit it, and I want to do it on specific page not on the home page for the posts.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, this code is what I was seeking

```
    <div>content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content.<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="jQuery('.show-more-toggle').toggle();" class="show-more-toggle v5-dark-link">show more</a><span class="show-more-toggle" style="display: none">more more more more more more more more more more more more more more more more more </span></div>
```